# Add custom attributes to a post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, shortcode, search

My blog is mainly composed of posts describing hiking. Actually, since I just moved from a Wordpress.com blog to a self-hosted Wordpress blog, every hike is inserted in a simple post.

However, every hike has certain parameters (e.g.: ascent, length, difficulty, ...) I'd like to save in the database in form of attribute and not simple text. My idea would be to use Wordpress to:

1. Automatically fill-in the hiking list page.
2. Add a search form that will help the reader to find the best hike for him, on the basis of certain parameters (for example: "I do not want to exceed 1'000 meters of ascent").

Essential requirement is that the permalink URLs will not change because the blog has been active for a few years.

I was wondering: might the *Wordpress Custom Post Types* work for my specific case? Or are there better solutions?

Might I use the *Custom Meta Boxes* for the hike's attributes like ascent, length and difficulty?

To create the hiking list page could I use the *Shortcodes*?

How can I implement the search form that will help the reader to find the best hike for him?

Comment: You're asking dozens of different questions - please stick with one per question, so it can be answered. Also: As it currently stands, there's no def. answer, as a lot of ways lead to the goal. Therefore your post will be close voted as "not constructive". Please read a little in the Codex, come back with an idea of what you want to do and show a little bit of code.

Comment: You're right, but in essence the question is only one: "how can I add custom attributes to a post?" However, in order to give a better context, I preferred to explain the current status and my goals. So who is more experienced than me can stop me and say "hey, maybe it's better if you do that" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at a couple of plugins to help out since you're just starting out.

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) will allow you to add the metadata to your current posts. Once you've added the custom fields, set it to display your Field box only on posts in the "hiking" category, for instance. You'll need to edit your theme to display the fields on single.php.

The searching/filtering is more challenging, but the [Relevanssi plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) is a good start. You should also look through this post for alternate suggestions if you're having trouble getting it working: [Advanced search form with filters for custom taxonomies and custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38361/advanced-search-form-with-filters-for-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-fields)

Best of luck!