# How to filter search results by post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I am able to filter tags archives by adding a parameter like ?post_type=slug to the url and this works fine except for search results. I mean where the url contains a search term like:

```
site.com/?s=searched&post_type=slug
```

How can i make the "&post_type=slug" also work in this case?

EDIT: It wasn't working on my end due to custom function.php code.

Comment: It should work out of the box, are you doing a custom query inside `search.php`?

Comment: I'm not, are you sure? I know it seems like it should but doesn't for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing something like calling `query_posts` or `WP_Query` on your search page?

Comment: E.g. https://tomjn.com/?s=talk&post_type=tomjn_talks vs https://tomjn.com/?s=talk it works on my site, what you're doing should be working. Something else is the problem

Comment: You are right. There's was custom code on functions.php adding all cpt to the is_search(), not sure why, it seems wp does that by default, maybe a left over from really old wp (or just plain wrong).

Comment: It would have been much better to write that as an answer instead of deleting the question, other users will be unable to use this if they have the same problem

Comment: I undeleted it and edited the title a bit. I have no right to make the answer if you do it i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By all rights it should work, here's the same thing applied to my own site:

tomjn.com/?s=talk&post_type=tomjn_talks vs tomjn.com/?s=talk . Something else is the problem

Specifically, if you replace the main query with a `query_posts` call or a `WP_Query`, that query won't take into account parameters passed via the URL unless explicitly passed through manually.

Instead, use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the main query, rather than creating a new query to replace it.This ensures any additional queries passed via the URL will also work, and reduces time spent querying the database significantly for a nice performance boost.

Additionally, if you already use `pre_get_posts`, setting the `post_type` will override the URL parameter, so you need to check for its existence

Answer (score 0):

The `s=keyword` url parameter is by default used to [search posts that contain that keyword](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter).

To customise this such as the post_type, you need to either:

1. build a [custom search page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page), you can also see this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140664/custom-search-query).  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802498/how-to-display-wordpress-search-results) also has some good examples.
2. Use a [plugin](http://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/12-wordpress-search-plugins-to-improve-your-site-search/)

Comment: sure, have a look at the 2nd answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802498/how-to-display-wordpress-search-results), there is an example of an html form where you could add an extra `<select>` dropdown field.  This form you need to display either in your sidebar, or header, or search  page.